# How can I implement my own ClientStore in IdentityServer4?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

I wanna add some extra columns (e.g. **ClientCustomProperty**) to the Client entity in IdentityServer4, and deal with them in my business layer so I'm creating my custom Store like this:

```
public class MyClientStore : IClientStore
{
    public Task<IdentityServer4.Models.Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

I want to return my **own Model** with extra columns (not the IdentityServer4.Models.Client) from the Store, but the IClientStore.FindClientByIdeAsync signature is:

```
Task<IdentityServer4.Models.Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId);
```

I think it should be something like this (Generic):

```
Task<TModel> FindClientByIdAsync<TModel>(string clientId)
    where TModel: class, IClientModel /* IClientModel is in IS4 */
```

What do I need to do to get my custom model?

Comment: You can change the implementation but not the interface; IS4 expects to get a `Client`. You could derive your own extended version from `Client`, or you could use the `Properties` collection it already contains to store your additional data.

Comment: I know I can't change the interface, and I want to add some columns to the Client entity that not already exists, i'm looking for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestions in my comment are possible solutions.  As long as you return a valid `Client` or `Client`-derived object to IS4 for `FindClientByIdAsync()`, you can store whatever you like against your Client.

---

Option 1: derive from `Client`:

```
public MyClient : Client
{
    public string MyExtraProperty { get; set; }
}

Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
{
   MyClient result = // fetch your client here;
   return result;
}
```

---

Option 2: adapt to `Client`:

```
public MyClient
{
    // Properties that Client requires, or can be adapted to what Client requires, here.
    // ...

    public string MyExtraProperty { get; set; }
}

Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
{
   MyClient result = // fetch your client here;
   return Adapt(result);
}

private Client Adapt(MyClient value)
{
    return // your-client-adapted-to-Client here;
}
```

As `Client` already contains a lot of data, this option makes less sense than the others.

---

Option 3: add to `Properties`:

Here you add your additional data to the `Client.Properties` collection.  IS4 will ignore it, but you can access the data wherever a `Client` instance is available.  This option requires no custom type or even a custom `IClientStore`; it's already supported.

Comment: OK thank you..let me check it out and let you know. BTW if you were me, which option would you choose?

Comment: In option 3, what do you mean by "IS4 will ignore it" ?

Comment: I mean IS4 ignores those properties; you can use them to store your own data. They will still be part of the `Client` object passed around though.

Comment: Re preference, depends on the type of additional data you're trying to store. I mostly use [the EF provider](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) for configuration, so in that scenario I would favour `Properties`, as it's all already done for you.  E.g. you might use that for an `AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut` flag where you want different Clients to behave differently in that regard.  You still have to code for a change like that, but you'll have your property/ies available to you in your code as long as you have the `Client`.